# Is there a function for Excel 2019 like index match or vlookup to find a value in a row added cross sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2019, index-match

I am running a report on Excel 2019 which has 2 sheets, and I want to automate the value in the field called Status in the sheet2 with the new status on sheet1 where a new row was added for the same item.

Ex:

[image: lOGIN STATUS]

thank you.

I tried index match, but a random update pull the data and new row is added down below and I lost my references.
The Max function is good as well considering the last date of status was pulled, but I need to select the whole column and the max function just bring me the same last date for everyone.

I want to get from sheet1 the last status for the same login updated in a new row added and take to sheet 2.

Comment: It would be better if you share the data as text so that we can copy & paste it instead of a picture

Comment: I am sorry @MayukhBhattacharya was my bad

Comment: Vlookup() and index() and match() work in Excel 2019.

Comment: I am trying to put this as text here but I have some difficult to do this be perfect and aligned

Answer (score 2):

### Lookup Last Occurrences Using `LOOKUP`

If `Status` is in `Sheet1!A1` and `STATUS` is in `Sheet2!B1` then in `Sheet2!B2` use the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!C$2:C$21=A2),Sheet1!A$2:A$21)
```

and copy down.

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008, I am going to try this too! thank you!!!

Comment: @P.b: No CSE is needed with this formula.

Comment: You're correct. I was mislead because it calculates an array.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is more **eloquent** way to do this, however this is what I have ***tried***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **F3**

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$22,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(
ROW($C$3:$C$22)&E3,ROW($C$3:$C$22)&$C$3:$C$22,0),"")))
```

Since its an array formula, you may need to press the `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` depending on your Excel Version

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic... it works!!!. Now I am going to try cross sheet. For now that's wonderful, thank you so much Mayukh Bhattacharya!!!